# Using std::transform on different data types

Tags: c++, transform, std, custom-data-type

I have a custom data type named atom. I want to use std::transform to fill a double vector with the atoms member "number" witch is a double. I get the error "std::vector::iterator’ has no member named ‘vec2’", where vec2 is my double vector.  Why is this? Is it even possible to use two different data types in transform?

atom.h

```
#ifndef _atom_
#define _atom_
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class atom{

public:

    bool operator==(const atom rhs);
    double number;
    string name;

};
#endif
```

atom.cpp

```
#include "atom.h"

atom::atom(){}

atom::~atom(){}

bool atom::operator==(const atom rhs){
    return this->name==rhs.name;

    }
```

transformation.h

```
#ifndef _transformation_
#define _transformation_
#include "atom.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


struct transformation{


    double operator() (atom a) const{

            return a.number;
        }



};
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
int main(){

    vector<atom> vec;


    atom hydro;
    atom oxy;
    atom carb;

    carb.name = "carbon";
    carb.number = 6;

    hydro.name="hydrogen";
    hydro.number=1;

    oxy.name="oxygen";
    oxy.number=8;

    vec.push_back(hydro);   //here i push atoms into my atom vector
    vec.push_back(oxy);
    vec.push_back(hydro);
    vec.push_back(oxy);
    vec.push_back(oxy);
    vec.push_back(carb);

    vector<double> vec2;
    transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(). vec2.begin(), transformation());
}
```

Comment: Don't edit this into a new question that invalidates the answer you got. I've rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typo: you have a `.` instead of a `,`:

```
transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(). vec2.begin(), transformation());
                                ^
```

`vec.end()` is an iterator, and `vec.end().vec2` attempts to access a member `vec2` of that iterator.

Next, you need to ensure that `vec2` is large enough to take the transformed elements. You can instantiate it such that it has the right size from the beginning:

```
vector<double> vec2(vec.size());
```

Comment: Oh. my mistake! Thanks for your help. But now I get a segmentation fault. What causes this?

Comment: @user3802252: You haven't sized `vec2`. You could fix this with a `vec2.resize(vec.size());` before your `tansform` call.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid. Apart from a typo in statement

```
transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(). vec2.begin(), transformation());
```

where you use period instead of comma the statement has a bug. Vector vec2 does not contain elements. So you may not use it in this statement such a way.

Either define the vector as

```
vector<double> vec2( vec.size() );

transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec2.begin(), transformation());
```

Or use the following approach

```
#include <iterator>
//...

vector<double> vec2;
vec2.reserve( vec.size() );

transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter( vec2 ), transformation());
```